# Beamer + hyperref + latex->dvips->ps2pdf

Tags: beamer, hyperref

i have a problem with this minimum code (i let all the packages for possible conflict) :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,dvips]{beamer} %Avec effet de transition
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[np]{numprint} 
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\definecolor{espeviolet}{RGB}{51,27,69}
\usecolortheme[named=espeviolet]{structure}
\useoutertheme[height=0pt]{sidebar}
%\setbeamercolor{sidebar left}{bg=espeviolet!40,fg=espeviolet}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=espeviolet!75,linkcolor=espeviolet!75}
\title{Test minimum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Page 1}


\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[label=test]{Page Test}

\begin{description}[<+->]
\item[Labas :] Blablabla \hfill \hyperlink{labas}{\beamergotobutton{}}
\end{description}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label = labas]{Page link}
 \hyperlink{test}{\beamergotobutton{}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The link don't works. They link to page 1.

Any idea ? Thx

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [**minimal working example (MWE)**](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Your code does not work at the moment. In addition, `utf8x` is outdated

Comment: After tracking down the compilation error to the `boadilla` theme and removing it, the document compiles and gives the right behaviour of the links (i.e. back and forth to `test` and `labas`)

Comment: The Boadilla theme does not compile in your document, that's why I disabled it.

Comment: @Pierre: I can compile your source without any change, and
can obtain a ps by
`dvips -z foo.dvi`. In the case of `ps2pdf` (gs-9.15),
test to labas is OK, but labas to test is NG.
In the case of `distiller` (Acrobat XI),
both of test to labas and labas to test are OK.
Thus `ps2pdf` in gs-9.15 may have problems.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Did you consider converting your comment into an answer? I think it explains where the error is an provides a workaround with distiller.

Comment: @samcarter: I have now tested again by gs-9.21. I think that the links work.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto even better reason to write an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that one of the links didn't work in the
case of Ghostscript-9.15.
I have now tested again by using the latest
Ghostscript-9.21, and have found that it works.

Comment: Thank you for removing this question from the list of unanswered!